# CSS: Best way to position a button to the right within a div when the screen width is above a certain value

Tags: html, css

I have the following div box:

[image]

```
<div class="requests-container">
  <div class="request-box">
    <div class="request-details">
      <h1>Table 6, 1:00PM</h1>
      <h2>
        Request made 10 min ago.
      </h2>
      <div class="status-button">
        <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.status-button {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.requests-container {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 200px;
  width: 66%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #a2e8dc;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
}

.request-details {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.request-button {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-size: 150% auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(114,240,218,1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.request-details h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #28bfa6;
}

.request-details h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

When the screen width is at least 1000px, I want the position of the button in the div to be like the following:

[image]

With the button centred vertically in the div and positioned to the right of the box.

I have tried to achieve this through the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .status-button {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-left: 700px;
  }
}
```

The above code gives me the following:

[image]

When I use padding-left to position the button to the right, the size of the button gets compressed. Not only that, when I make the screen size smaller, the button escapes the div box:

[image]

What is the best way to position my button to the right such that the size of the button does not shrink and the button remains contained in the div box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `position: absolute`, `padding` and `transform`. You can use a flex layout to solve it.

Use `displat: flex`, `flex-wrap: wrap`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: space-between` in the button element.

So, for status-button element, you use `width: 100%` and in media query, you set `width: auto`.

```css
.status-button {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

.requests-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.request-box {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    height: 200px;
    width: 66%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #a2e8dc;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
}

.request-details {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 30px;
    height: 100%;
}

.request-button {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-size: 150% auto;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(141,227,227,1) 0%, rgba(114,240,218,1) 100%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.request-details h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #28bfa6;
}

.request-details h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .status-button {
      width: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Requests Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="requests.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="requests-container">
            <div class="request-box">
                <div class="request-details">
                    <div>
                      <h1>Table 6, 1:00PM</h1>
                      <h2>Request made 10 min ago.</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="status-button">
                        <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example at codepen
https://codepen.io/themustafaomar/pen/poJOLqE?editors=1100

```
.requests-container {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 66%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: #a2e8dc;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #ededed;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.request-button {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background-size: 150% auto;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(141, 227, 227, 1) 0%,
    rgba(114, 240, 218, 1) 100%
  );
  cursor: pointer;
}

.request-details h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #28bfa6;
}

.request-details h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .requests-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="requests-container">
    <div class="request-details">
      <h1>Table 6, 1:00PM</h1>
      <h2>Request made 10 min ago.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="status-button">
      <button type="button" class="request-button">Assistance Requested</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace in your css file the following to achive your goal:

```
.status-button {
margin-left: 25rem;
margin-top: -5rem;
```

}

and

```
.request-button {
height:0;
```

}